# Looping a prompt until user decides to terminate program

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops, do-loops

this is my first post. I am trying to build a basic js program that will prompt user to "Enter a hero to see if they are in the array". The program executes as intended, except I would like for the prompt after my first "do{", to keep prompting the user until the user inputs "Q" (Yes I'm very new to this). 
Instead, my program stops prompting the user after the hero was =found.
Thanks, Sarah.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Program name: Review
            //Purpose: Allow user to search through array for hero
            // Author: Sarah
            //DLM: 15 Jan 2017
        var more;       //continue looping?
        var hero;       // hero to search for in the array
        var ES = "";    //Space
        var BR = "<br/>"; 
        var ARRAYSIZE = 4;
        var found=false;

        //array of superheroes
        var superheroes = new Array("batman", "superman", "spiderman", "hulk");

        //continue until user wants to quit
        do{ 
            hero = prompt("Enter a hero to see if they are in array.", ES);

            //to lower case
            hero.toLowerCase = hero;

            // loop through heroes, checks if user entered hero is contained within
            for (index=0; index < 4; index++){
                   if (superheroes[index].toLowerCase() == hero){
                        found=true;
                        break;
               }
            }
            if(found){
                document.write(superheroes[index] + " is in the array." + BR)
                quit="Q";
            }else{
                quit = prompt("Hero not found. Do you want to continue? (Y for yes, Q to quit)", ES);
            }
        }while (quit.toUpperCase() != "Q");
 </script>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you set it to Q when it is found..... So if you do not want it to stop, than you should remove that line....

Comment: btw, `hero.toLowerCase() = hero;` needs `()` for calling the method.

Comment: shouldn't it also be `hero = hero.toLowerCase();` ?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you want the program to keep prompting, even when the hero was found?

In that case I suggest removing this line: `quit="Q";`

Answer (score 0):

You quit because of:

```
quit="Q";
```

Also missing a semicolon in the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is stopping because of an error. Check your console.

`hero.toLowerCase = hero;` is backwards. It should be `hero=hero.toLowerCase();` Also, instead of looping you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) or [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to see if the hero is in the array.

If you want the program to ask for a "Q" when the hero is found remove the else and put the quit prompt underneath, that way it is asked every time.

```js
//Program name: Review
//Purpose: Allow user to search through array for hero
// Author: Sarah
//DLM: 15 Jan 2017
var hero; // hero to search for in the array
var ES = ""; //Space
var BR = "<br/>";
var found = false;
var quit;

//array of superheroes
var superheroes = new Array("batman", "superman", "spiderman", "hulk");

//continue until user wants to quit
do {
  hero = prompt("Enter a hero to see if they are in array.", ES);

  //to lower case
  hero = hero.toLowerCase();

  // checks if user entered hero is contained within
  found = superheroes.indexOf(hero) > -1;
  
  if (found) {
    document.write(hero + " is in the array." + BR);
  }

  quit = prompt("Do you want to continue? (Y for yes, Q to quit)", ES);

} while (quit.toUpperCase() != "Q");
```

Comment: OP also wants "to keep prompting the user until the user inputs 'Q' " looks like your example stops after it finds a hero.

Answer (score 0):

After the hero prompt line, inside the do loop.

```
if (hero.charAt(0) == 'Q') break;
```

This will check if the first character of the hero is a capital Q.
If it is, it breaks out of the do while loop and you're done.